# How to compute the *vertical* distance between a point and a triangle in 3D?

Tags: triangles, 3d

The point is either above or under the triangle i.e. if you project the point and the triangle on the ground, the point lies in the triangle.

I want the distance DD' (in dark red) on the Z axis of the point to the triangle given the carthesian coordinates of A, B, C and D. See diagram. Z is used as the altitude, it's placed correctly on the diagram.

[image: diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compute $$\frac{(D-A)\cdot n}{e_3\cdot n}$$ where $n=(B-A)\times (C-A)$.

Comment: This answer is a bit unclear to me. What is e_3 in this formula? Is the 'x' a cross product between the two vectors (seems logical)? Any reason or insights why this is true?

Comment: e_1..3 are the frame unit vectors (axis x, y, z). x is the cross product indeed.